# Is correct use vuejs with cshtml and a js (without webpack)

Tags: asp.net, .net, vue.js, .net-core

Is a good practice work Vuejs with a unique .js file (all logic there) with a cshtml? like angular 1.0.

Happen that i need mix .net core action controller with Vuejs, it is not a vuejs app, I want use vuejs as my tool to refresh the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a template that combines **.NET** with **Vue.js**. You can use it as a starting point or an example.

GitHub: https://github.com/danijelh/aspnetcore-vue-typescript-template

Comment: Thank you so much!!